# Can’t start kong in docker

Tags: docker, kong

I tried to start kong following the docker guide at https://getkong.org/install/docker/ but getting

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: exec: kong: not found
```

Heres my command log:

```
❯ docker run -d --name kong-database \
              -p 5432:5432 \
              -e "POSTGRES_USER=kong" \
              -e "POSTGRES_DB=kong" \
              postgres:9.4
Unable to find image 'postgres:9.4' locally
9.4: Pulling from library/postgres
4176fe04cefe: Pull complete
b3acc6da98ed: Pull complete
ef28401016a4: Pull complete
f53d3f24be68: Pull complete
faa03ed01c16: Pull complete
2bd2f4dc2cd2: Pull complete
18fbef78dc91: Pull complete
b7e59e2fc7b6: Pull complete
e1f7a65ca8e6: Pull complete
74bf61bfc5b0: Pull complete
2dce4269ba10: Pull complete
b99df6b6744e: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:6c4d8fd87439a6e7db3c0b3c1edc7beb3ce8df8e30c0589b383a7b1911f21db0
Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:9.4
967b18ba1ea3a03e788221b22f55fc33d5c661c7abeefca7ee66c8e3adecf637

~/code/docker-kong master 1m 45s
❯ docker run --rm \
    --link kong-database:kong-database \
    -e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" \
    -e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" \
    -e "KONG_CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS=kong-database" \
    kong:latest kong migrations up
Unable to find image 'kong:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/kong
af4b0a2388c6: Pull complete
a60d79b10ccb: Pull complete
9261ce38e5a9: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:225fea7355e6dc845cfb3f02307237be9aba4d8f852819ce067c96333dde0538
Status: Downloaded newer image for kong:latest
/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: exec: kong: not found
```

Is there anything else I should do to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kong has updated new version on Dockerhub and may be the latest version has error.
I used another version and it's work.

Example: Change image `kong:latest` to `kong:0.12-alpine`.